# Google web fonts (FF & IE issue)

Tags: google-webfonts

I have a problem with Google web fonts.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" />
</head>

<body>

<h1 style="font-family:'Open Sans'">Open Sans text</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

This works in Chrome, Safari & Opera, but doesn't work in FF & IE. Any opinions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Web Fonts not working on ie9 and firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780730/google-web-fonts-not-working-on-ie9-and-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue. A fix for Firefox and IE9 users is rolling out now. Thanks for reporting the issue!

(I'm an engineer on Google Web Fonts)