# Google Web Fonts not working on ie9 and firefox

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

Hey guys google web fonts not loading on Firefox and ie9. Yesterday they was working good but today no luck. Does anyone else having this problem?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marvel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
.a{ font-family:'Marvel', sans-serif;}
</style>
.
.
<div class="a">Example Text</div>
```

working on all browsers except of ie9 and firefox..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google web fonts (FF & IE issue)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776648/google-web-fonts-ff-ie-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the same for me, with "Terminal Dosis" font, since a few hours. I guess it's a temporary problem from Google server (I hope it will fixed soon). If you're in a hurry, you could use a solution like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ or https://typekit.com/

;)

Comment: Well, Google Web Fonts is back :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known issue. A fix for Firefox and IE9 users is rolling out now. Thanks for reporting the issue!

(I'm an engineer on Google Web Fonts)

Comment: What's the status on this one?